# How to remember and use a variable again in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

The thing that I'm trying to do is remember the lowest number of a numbericUpDown and fill it in a label, but only the lowest.

So numbericupdown has an option to go from 1-1000 on attempts tried.
If the user tried 300 times and clicks a button, he must see the label of lower-tries go to 300.

If he does it again and succeeds in 100 times the number 300 must change to 100 with a button click. This is where it gets tricky for me. Because the next thing I want to achieve is that if the user tries once more in 200 tries, the code must still be showing the 100 as lowest. I can't get it done.

```
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(updown_tries.Value);

        label_lowest.Text = Convert.ToString(number);

        if(number <= Convert.ToInt32(label_lowest.Text))
        {
            label_lowest.Text = Convert.ToString(number);
        }
```

Comment: Remove the first `label_lowest.Text = Convert.ToString(number);`

Comment: Just did so, number remains 0 and doesn't change at all

Comment: This is for Windows Forms, right? Not ASP.NET or anything like that? Please tag your post.

Comment: in addition to what Johnny said, change the if statement to if(label_lowest.Text == "0" || number <= Convert.ToInt32(label_lowest.Text)). I'm assuming the user can't have success with 0 tries.

Comment: Would love to help here, but I think I need more information as to how it is intended to work. By your comment, you're saying it remains 0 and doesn't move if you just check if the number you're currently at is lower than the current minimum, so you apparently want to increase the floor as it moves up. Your item appears to be able to go up or down, but in your 300/100/200 clicks scenario, you don't state which direction these clicks are moving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the current number is smaller than the lowest number registered in the textbox.
You also need to check whether the textbox is null.

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(updown_tries.Value);

int lowest = 0;

if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(label_lowest.Text))
{
    lowest = Convert.ToInt32(label_lowest.Text);
}

if(number < lowest || lowest == 0)
{
    label_lowest.Text = Convert.ToString(number);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, i got it working now. I really appreciate the effort!

Answer (score -1):

> So numbericupdown has an option to go from 1-1000 on attempts tried. If the user tried 300 times and clicks a button, he must see the label of lower-tries go to 300. If he does it again and succeeds in 100 times the number 300 must change to 100 with a button click.

WUT

> How to remember and use a variable again in c#?

If you need to persist a value between events, just add it to the form as a field or member variable, e.g.

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    protected int NumberOfTries = 0;

    //Rest of your code

}
```

Then to access it just type `this.` and you should see it pop up in intellisense.

```
int number = this.NumberOfTries;
```